# Disable selected options in v-autocomplete in vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using this auto-complete [`autocomplete`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmyvVy?editors=1111)

There are two options that are selected by default i don't want to remove those options. How can i do that in v-autocomplete?

Comment: The Code Pen link is blank!

Comment: Don't add `close` in `v-chip` for first 2 entry?

Comment: i remove the `close` completely but still i can unselect the options, and i can use the backspace as well to remove those selected options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the investigation, i got the solution to this. Just need to modify the items

```
{ name: 'test', disabled: true }
```

Just pass the `disabled: true`, it will disable the options so that you cannot select and cannot be removed if that option is already selected.